# On loading an assembly/dll after a method is invoked via reflection, the method invocation throws "Object does not match target type" exception

Tags: c#, exception, reflection, load, .net-assembly

I have a test tool developed using *.net framework c#*. I have a *DLL* which contains all the interfaces to and method that need to be invoked during *runtime*.

The *application* is started and this loads the *assembly* to memory using `Assembly.Load(ReadAllBytes(path))` method and once the *assembly* is loaded, the *types* are fetched and required methods are invoked via reflection.

But after *invoking* a method if I load the assembly again and try invoking the same method, I get an exception from `RunMethodInfo` class `CheckConsistency` method.

> "Object does not match target type"

Is it not possible to load the *assembly* after calls are made through reflection?

If I never run any method and load the *assembly* several times before, everything works fine. I am not understanding which object it is referring to ? Kindly help.

Comment: Please learn from the edits i made, putting a massive thought bubble into one paragraph is hard to read and does you no favours asking a question

Comment: @TheGeneral _too_ many _italics_ hurt _readability_ IMO

Comment: @stuartd I *see* no *problem* with *my* over *italicised* **edits**  :)

Comment: This is my first time asking a question on a community, will keep in mind all the above points from now on.